# SQL Server 2008 R2 Insert Stored Procedure Syntax with Identity Field

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, identity-column

Good Afternoon,

I've written a very basic stored procedure that will be used to insert QuestionText and QuestionStatus into the Questions table with QuestionID int Primary Key set as having Identity.

The syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertNewQuestion 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@QuestionText varchar(200), @QuestionStatus bit
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT into Questions
(QuestionText,QuestionStatus) 
Values
(@QuestionText),(@QuestionStatus)
END
GO
```

When I execute the stored procedure, I receive the following error:

There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES
 clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns
 specified in the INSERT statement.

What is the correct syntax to use to properly insert a record and allow for QuestionID to auto-increment upon each insertion?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

**Updated Stored Procedure Syntax**

Comment: Your Values line is still closing parantheses around each parameter. They are all supposed to be in one parantheses separated by comma's. Values (@QuestionText, @QuestionStatus)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove QuestionID and @@Identity + Values should be (@QuestionText,@QuestionStatus)

```
INSERT into Questions
(QuestionText,QuestionStatus) 
Values
(@QuestionText,@QuestionStatus)
```

SQL Server knows that QuestionID is an Identity field and will increment it.... :-)

If you need to return the Identity that was inserted then create an out parameter on the SP and get it by calling SCOPE_IDENTITY().

SET @QuestionID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify the identity columns, and the values are not supposed to be in their own parenthesis.

```
INSERT into Questions
(QuestionText,QuestionStatus) 
Values
(@QuestionText, @QuestionStatus)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT into Questions (QuestionText,QuestionStatus)  
Values (@QuestionText,@QuestionStatus)
```

i.e. without the identity field specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPWITHPARAMETER_AND_RETURN_VALUE
  (
    @EMPID INT,
    @IDVAL INT,   
    @RETURNVALUE INT =0 OUT
  )
  AS 
    DECLARE @COUNT INT
  BEGIN
  SELECT @COUNT=COUNT(*) FROM JOINTABLE WHERE EMPID=@EMPID AND IDVAL=@IDVAL
    IF(@COUNT >0)
      BEGIN

           SET @RETURNVALUE = 1;
                             PRINT @RETURNVALUE    
            RETURN @RETURNVALUE
              END
         ELSE
       BEGIN
            SET @RETURNVALUE = 1;
                              PRINT @RETURNVALUE
            RETURN @RETURNVALUE
                        END
  END
```